# Why can I no longer remove mails?

Tags: mail.app

In one of my mailboxes, I can no longer remove e-mails. Every time I want to delete a mail, it gives me the following message:

> "247263.emlx" couldn't be copied to "Messages" because an item with the same name already exists.

I have already tried to rebuild the mailbox, but without any result.

How can I fix this issue?

*(MacBook Pro Retina, Mid 2012, OS X 10.11.4)*

Comment: Are you using pop3 or imap4

Comment: I am using IMAP.

Comment: How full is your "deleted" folder

Comment: I have 2581 in the Thrash folder and 5626 in the Archive folder.

Comment: Try deleting some and sorry for the late reply I only just got the notification....